# Getting Error while implementing Fragmentation in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting error everytime when I run my Fragment API example application. It is referenced from Android Developers Guide http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html.
I don't know how it returns the error and why? Please suggest anything you see that will get me the right result.

**Error Stack:**

```
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment/com.example.fragment.FragmentExampleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1777)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.example.fragment.FragmentExampleActivity.onCreate(FragmentExampleActivity.java:11)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  ... 11 more
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.fragment$TitlesFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:500)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:468)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4081)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  ... 20 more
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.fragment$TitlesFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.fragment-1.apk]
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:490)
01-03 11:54:55.255: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  ... 23 more
```

**layout-land/fragment_layout.xml:**

```
<fragment class="com.example.fragment$TitlesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
```

**layout/fragment_layout.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="com.example.fragment$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the fragment name field as

```
<fragment
    android:name="my.package.name.classname"
    //other stuff
    />
```

rather than just putting the name of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.

make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore.

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.fragment$TitlesFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Also make sure that your fragment class is public

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
```

when declaring your fragment class. Also, you shouldn't have any constructor in the class. So make sure that you don't have one.

Comment: **"you shouldn't have any constructor in the class"** - is this correct? I mean, I suppose we can have constructors in the class, but we need to have also an empty constructor. The error is clear to me: **make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public.** What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the runtime is not able to find TitlesFragment while creating the activity

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.fragment$TitlesFragment
```

Comment: What is the Java package name of TitlesFragment class you created?